# What's with the porch lights?

Tags: the-strangers, the-strangers-prey-at-night

Something I noticed while watching [The Strangers: Prey At Night](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1285009/), is the porch lights.

1. When the family arrives at their trailer, the porch light is off. After the 2nd time the girl knocks on the door, Mike (the father) screws the porch light bulb in so it turns on.
2. When Mike and Luke go back to Uncle Marv's trailer, the porch light is off when they enter. When Luke is going to make his run (but stops at the door when he sees the bad guy), the porch light is ON. When Mike and Luke finally make their run out of Marv's trailer, the light of OFF again. What's the deal here? The trailer had no power...
3. When Cindy and Kinsey return to their trailer, the porch light is OFF. When Mike and Luke return, the light is ON, when they exit the trailer and head to the van, the light is OFF.

Some of the events can be explained by the bad guys, like when everyone leaves trailer 47, the bad guys would have turned the light off, but the biggest example of wtf is in Marv's trailer when Luke and David are trying to leave. The bad guys didn't make it to the porch, but the light was on, then off.

I'm thinking it's more than just a mistake because the point that Marv's trailer had no power was made clear more than once.

Comment: I'm not saying your question is bad... not in the slightest... but was the movie so dull you were distracted by the practical lighting? ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin haha! The movie was actually pretty good and I have high standards for horror movies, but years on Movies & TV SE has changed the way I watch movies :D

Comment: LOL - appreciate it. My entire way of watching changed when at the age of 52 I actually joined the industry - movies will never be the same again. ;)

Comment: The porch light is a recurring thing in these movies.  Remember in the first one where the porch light was unscrewed when the creepy girl came to the door a few times?  The porch light was always unscrewed because she didn't have her mask on and you couldn't see her face with the light being off.  James actually screws it back in in the first one, too.

Comment: I really hope that you watched the first one!  It's so much more suspenseful than this one was.  This one was more of a slasher movie in comparison to the creepiness and suspense of the first one :)